# Facebook friends list returns empty

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application I'm trying to retrieve the user's friends list.
I ask for user_friends permission and check in the activity the the permission is granted.
The problem is that the friends list returns empty at any time.

I use the following code:

```
        Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(_session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> listFacebookFriends, Response response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+listFacebookFriends.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        }
    });

    request.executeAsync();
```

And the returned response is:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you created your app after 4/30/2014 which means that you are using v2.0 of the API. That means that only friends that are using the app will get returned.

Comment: so how can I get the whole friends list (even friends which not using my app)? @WizKid

Comment: It is not possible to get all friends. There are new apis to let you do some of the things you could do with all friends. Like taggable friends, invitable friends and social context.

But getting all friends are not possible.

Comment: Is it safe to use this feature with an app that was created before that data?

Comment: It is safe to use it until 4/30/2015. After that point no app will get all friends