# Android Getting Facebook friend list with SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying all day to get all my Facebook friend list using Facebook SDK 3.0
I don't want to use the FriendPickerFragment, since i don't want to display a picker, i want to create my own list of friends (displaying the name and image).

According to this post [Facebook friends list returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616071/facebook-friends-list-returns-empty)  this is possible only if a friend approves your app, but even when i tried this with my wife's account and mine, i'm still not able to get the friend list.

any help will be highly appreciated, I've spend so much time on this and reach a dead lock.

Thanks!

Comment: Did both you and your wife grant user_friends permission to the app?

Comment: I think so, i don't see my app on my FB account, but when i was asked to grant permission, i did

Comment: debug the access tokens and see if they have the permissions

Comment: Sorry for asking, but how?

Comment: when i check session.getPermission() i see that it's size is 0, although i approved friend_list for sure...

Comment: one more thing that might give some light, when i check it via graph explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/330235737130347/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.0 i see only me... and not my friend list (but i do see that the permissions are )

Comment: That query that you did in graph explorer should only return your id and name not friends

Comment: ok, from this query https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/330235737130347/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriendlists&version=v2.0 i was able to see my friend list, but i still can't make it to work from my app

Comment: That is because Graph Explorer is using API v1.0 and not v2.0 like your app. Make sure to select your app in Graph Explorer in the top and you will see it works the same as in your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precondition: 
1. Create an app on facebook.
2. Add hash code of android app into facebook app.

Android app:
get permission (on your fb account who created fb app)

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info, user_friends"));
```

authButton is com.facebook.widget.LoginButton (you can refer sample apps to find out how the login button works)

Method to get friend list:

```
   Request r = new Request(session, "/me/friends", null,HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            try {
                                GraphObject graphObj = response.getGraphObject();
                                if(graphObj != null){
                                    ArrayList<FBFriend> friendArrayList = new ArrayList<FBFriend>();
                                    JSONObject jsonObj = graphObj.getInnerJSONObject();
                                    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray(DATA_NODE);
                                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                                        JSONObject Jobj = (JSONObject)array.get(i);
                                        String id = Jobj.getString(FBFriend.ID_NOTE);
                                        String name = Jobj.getString(FBFriend.NAME_NOTE);
                                        FBFriend f = new FBFriend(id, name);
                                        friendArrayList.add(f);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
r.executeAsync()
```

Comment: if my answer does not help you, plz unmarked the answer.

Comment: What are DATA_NODE, ID_NOTE, NAME_NOTE?