# Android getting friends list with names and profile picture (SDK 3)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After i got answer to my previous question: [Android Getting Facebook friend list with SDK 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099259/android-getting-facebook-friend-list-with-sdk-3-0)
Now i'm able to get friend list, but I'm not getting the friend's name and picture... i'm getting id, i'm getting name (but it's not user's full name, it's something else)

once I've the friend ID, do i now need to download the data for each friend?

Thanks,
Gidi

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found my problem.
i used me/friendlist and should have used me/friends